# Error when calling MainActivity method from another class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have the following api call in my `MainActivity.cs` -

```
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        var progressDialog = ShowLoading(_instance);

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var objectResponse = string.Empty;
            string _apiUrl = "https://my-web-service-endpoint";

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_apiUrl);
            request.Method = "GET";

            using (var response = _request.HttpWebResponse(request))
            {
                objectResponse = _request.HttpWebResponseBody(response);
            }

            progressDialog.Dismiss();
        });
    }
```

I am calling this method from a button click in `SliderControl.cs` -

```
    public void loadTestView(View view)
    {
        Button btnDoSomething = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDoSomething);
        if (btnDoSomething != null)
        {
            btnDoSomething .Click += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                 await MainActivity.GetInstance().DoSomething();
            };
        }
    }
```

However `loadTestView` is not called in the `MainActivity.cs` rather it is called when a used swipes onto a specific view in the application and handled in the `SliderControl.cs` , it is set like -

```
public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
            {
                var selectedView = Resource.Layout.Locator;

                if (position == 0)
                {
                    selectedView = Resource.Layout.Main;
                }
                if (position == 1)
                {
                    selectedView = Resource.Layout.TestView;
                }

                View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(selectedView, container, false);
                container.AddView(view);

                if (position == 0)
                {
                    loadMainView(view);
                }
                else if (position == 1)
                {
                    loadTestView(view);
                }

                return view;
            }
```

When I set a different buttons click event logic in the `MainActivity.cs` everything working accordingly, however when setting the button click login as it is above, I am met with the error -

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

The odd thing is the loader does actually come into view, however when I step into the `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>` line the error hits.

I have tried changing the line to use `Task.Run` instead but same error, and also found some info on `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` hwoever believe this is for Xamarin Forms. How can I get this to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340476/getting-viewrootimplcalledfromwrongthreadexception-when-calling-invalidate-func/51340661#51340661

Comment: Do you invoke another activity's method from current activiy ?Why not using service to do other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the UI Thread to update the UI / or any task that involve the UI:

**Xamarin Forms Example:**

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  label.Text = "Async operation completed";
});
```

John wrote the great examples describing how to use Async/Await pattern. You may want to read more here https://johnthiriet.com/configure-await/#

**Update: For Xamarin Native -**

**Problem:**

```
new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
    lblTest.Text = "updated in thread"; 
    // Doesn't work because you can't modify UILabel on background thread!
})).Start();
```

**Solution:**

```
new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
    InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        label1.Text = "updated in thread"; 
        // this works! We are invoking in Main thread.
    });
})).Start();
```

Comment: He is using native Android, not Forms.